# Grep multiple text files with each file outputs in new line

Tags: search, sed, command-line, grep

i have 4 text files with this contents :

**text1.txt**

```
<a data-role="sku" data-code="1">
      ...
<a data-role="sku" data-code="2">
```

**text2.txt**

```
<a data-role="sku" data-code="19">
      ...
<a data-role="sku" data-code="48">
<a data-role="sku" data-code="93">
```

**text3.txt**

```
this file text not have any date-code
```

**text4.txt**

```
<a data-role="sku" data-code="333">
<a data-role="sku" data-code="444">
```

how can i use **grep** to get output like this

i want each text file outputs in new line and if text file not have exact match then will be replace by **NO**

```
1,2
19,48,93
NO
333,444
```

.

i try this `grep -oP '(?<="data-code":")[^"]*' text*` 
but i get results like this :

```
1
2
19
48
93
333
444
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `grep`?

Comment: @Cyrus RavinderSingh13 has answer usin awk its working fine, there is other methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(if you are good with `awk`):

```
awk -F'[",]' '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  if(val){
     print val
  }
  val=""
}
/Code/{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$(NF-2)
}
END{
  if(val){
     print val
  }
}' *.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1,2
7,9,14
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed Input_file's style a bit in comments so edited code as per it  now.

```
awk -F'"' '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  if(val){
     print val
  }
  val=""
}
/data-code/{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$2
}
END{
  if(val){
     print val
  }
}' *.txt
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** As per OP's comment, OP need to print `NO` for a Input_file where NO match is found, then following may help.

```
awk -F'"' -v val="begin" '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  if(val!="begin"){
    print val?val:"NO"
  }
  val=""
}
/data-code/{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$(NF-1)
}
END{
  print val?val:"NO"
}' *.txt
```

Comment: Its working Thank Youuuu!!! 
What about 
text1.txt
data-code="1"><group>
data-code="2"><group>

text2.txt
data-code="1"><group>
data-code="2"><group>
data-code="4"><group>
data-code="7"><group>

Comment: @H.Otmane, Also edit your post with your new Input_file sample too(keep both) so that all could know it.

Comment: thanks for your help. i edit my question, sorry for this because im new in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i read this article link, im sure that your answer will be accepted, check my Edit please

Comment: its not working, ouputs is : line 1 = sku,sku,sku,sku,sku,sku,sku
line 2 = sku,sku,sku

Comment: @H.Otmane, not fair :) you have completely changed the input_files I changed EDIT2 code now let me know?

Comment: @H.Otmane, Np, glad that it helped you, all codes worked :) Try to keep samples and question same in first time itself. Cheers and enjoy learning on this great site SO.